# recursive function has out_of_range exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, recursion, backtracking, outofrangeexception

Given a global vector `list` of ASCII codes and corresponding number values and a string, like `000.00-000.0.0.0`, this function takes an `input` token strings 2-char or 3-char long and replaces it with a single ASCII symbol that represents the number value between 0 and 184, then returns the shortened string without deliminator as `out`. Also, in reverse (direction 1) given the ASCII symbol it converts back to the number string and returns.

```
//looks for input string in vector and returns output, 'c' is check row, 'r' is return row
string vectorSearch(string &check, int n, int c, int r) 
{
    if (check.length() <= 1) 
        return check;
    if (list[n][c] == check || list[n][c] == ('0'+check)) //adds leading zero if 2char long
        return list[n][r];
    else 
        return vectorSearch (check, ++n, c, r);
}

//this function takes an ontology and either changes from single char 
//to string or takes strings and converts to char representation
string Lexicon::convertOntology(string input, int direction, string out, string temp) 
{
    if (input == "" && temp == "") 
        return out; //check for completed conversion
    else {
        if (input[0] == '.' || input[0] == '-' || input == "") { //found deliniator or endk
            if (input != "") return convertOntology(input.substr(1),direction, 
                 out+=vectorSearch(temp, 0, direction, 1-direction), "");
            else return convertOntology("", direction, 
                 out+=vectorSearch(temp, 0, direction, 1-direction), "");
        } else 
            return convertOntology(input.substr(1), direction, out, temp+=input[0]); //increment and check
    }
}
```

These functions work fine except for on output after the last char is parsed. With a break on the line `return convertOntology(input.substr(1), direction, out+=add, temp);` there is an error when `input == ""` and `temp == "0"` - the last pass through `vectorSearch()` should clear the temp and add the temp char to the out string, since the temp is == 1char then it should be returned from `vectorSearch()` as it is. Then clear the `convertOntology()` return check of `input` and `temp == ""`. But, it never reaches a break on the first line of `vectorSearch()` and there is an

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77bc15de exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0035cf1c
```

What is going on? Is this an issue with recursion backtracking through returns and I am missing a return somewhere to break the recursion loop?

Comment: I might have found it; on the last round input.substr(1) is called on string ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the case where `temp == ""` and `input != ""` you call `input.substr(1)` which is, well, out of range.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Even if you don't get to the else part,</strike>

```
input.substr(1)
```

will throw an exception when the `input` string is exactly one character long.

Seems it doesn't - `input.substr(input.size())` is allowed, and returns an empty string.

---

You will later likely have a similar problem in VectorSearch. If there is no match, you will increment `n` until it gets out of range.

Comment: catching the no match case - that is a feature saved for the next version. I will test the input.substr(1) with 1 char, it seemed this was OK on the first round.

Comment: I added this hack of a fix `if (check.length() <= 1 || n > 200) `

Comment: Yes, I was wrong - it actually is ok. The requirement for `pos` in `substr(pos)` is `pos <= size()`, not `pos < size()` as I assumed. That is odd. So `substr(1)` will get you an empty string when `size() == 1`.